# How to build the Adobe Brackets editor?

Tags: compiling

My aim is to install the Adobe Brackets editor and am following the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-Brackets-Shell).

I'm at the point of running the `grunt setup` command. My problem is, the instructions stop at this point.

What are the remaining steps I need to take in order to install the Brackets editor?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on armhf architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
   sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d libnspr4-0d gyp gtk+-2.0
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nodejs
   sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
   npm install
   ```
2. Go to your source folders, eg:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/src
   cd ~/src
   ```
3. Clone the repositories

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell.git
   git clone https://github.com/adobe/brackets.git
   ```
4. Build

   ```
   cd brackets-shell
   grunt setup
   grunt build
   ```

Comment: Thanks for these steps. At the point I run `grunt setup`, I get the error `Cannot find module 'q'`. Any ides how to fix that?

Comment: Now I can only guess: `sudo npm install q`

Comment: Thanks, did that. Now lots more errors introduced. I think those will be answered by different questions.